# Cannot install Equalizer plugin for Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, equalizer

I followed the instructions, and when I typed the last command:
*"sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-complete"*, I got the following error:
*"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rhythmbox-plugin-complete"*
I run Mint 21.1. Also, under Edit, there is no option  "Plugins" -> Enable "Equalizer".

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, Linux Mint is not supported by this forum. But, you may try installing the `rhythmbox-plugin-equalizer` package from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Efossfreedom/+archive/ubuntu/rhythmbox-plugins)